How to hold the SIM call?
I have voip call app. When I am on the SIM call, if I am getting the voip call via my app, I want to hold the personal call.
Is this possible? If then solutions please...
If I mute the SIM call with default phone app, microphone is getting muted or specific audio route for personal call is getting muted?
If specific audio route for personal is getting muted, how can I handle this audio route?
And how about the speaker?
I didn't hold the SIM call. so I used AudioManager to mute the SIM call, but in this case, voip call is getting muted as well

I don't think that's possible .. you do other way around .. If SIM call is active or there is an incoming call and user picks that SIM call then you hold the VOIP call just like every other calling app does ..

Thanks @SpiritCrusher. when I am on the SIM call, I can get the event for voip call like RINGING, ACCEPTED, ... But when I am on the voip call, I can't get the event for SIM call like RINGING, ACCEPTED... Is it possible to get the event for SIM call when I am on the voip call? To get the event, I am using TelephonyManager and PhoneStateListener
